# How to convert port number to network byte order?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I am writing a program which would determine the process id of the port in C#.Net.

There is a function `GetExtendedTcpTable` in `IpHlpApi.dll` which returns TcpTable. After getting the table, I am iterating through the rows and parsing the port number.

Now for comparing the Port numbers, I am converting 27144 Port number to network byte order using `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder` and comparing with other Port number using `Marshal.ReadInt32`. The comparison is not working. i.e. No result match.

If instead of using `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder`, I use the following logic

```
((27144 & 0xFF) << 8) + ((27144 & 0xFF00) >> 8) == Marshal.ReadInt32(portAddress)
```

I am able to determine the process id i.e. one of the results match.

Can you please tell me why `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder` is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using the `DWORD` from `dwLocalPort`/`dwRemotePort` in [TcpRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The DWORD is certainly not going to be 16-bits, and you'll likely call the 32-bit version of [IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.hosttonetworkorder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)... you should try to cast it as an `Int16` before using the `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder` function.

Comment: For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329627%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @utopianheaven: using `Int16` returns `-5527` and using the value as is i.e. `Int32` returns `-362217472`. whereas when I use the shift logic, the value returned is `60009`.

Comment: @jags: You're nearly there... notice that `-5527 + (2^16) = 60009`.  You'll need to use the `Int16` version of IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder (since `UInt16` is unavailable), but then compare them as `UInt16`s.

Comment: After casting the result to `UInt16`, I am getting `60009`. So it is the signed nature of `Int32` was creating the confusion for me. Thank you! I will study more on this stuff for my own learning.